# Получить массив из jsonb в функции plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
xyz int [];

abc jsonb := ["1150,2021-02-22 13:24:04.587018+02,a39b5ab0-5812-4f.",
              "1151,2021-02-22 12:36:13.282165+02,a98f9ab0-5611-4f.",
              "1153,2021-02-22 12:36:13.282165+02,e36c3506-791b-4c."];

как на основе abc получить такой массив xyz ?
[1150, 1151, 1153]
```

Comment: ? получить количество элементов, потом abc ->> по ним; и из каждой строки вытягивать ... _как с текстом_  или string_to_array и по элементу ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что необходимо получить данные до запятой из каждой строки JSON-массива, то так:

```
xyz := array(
    select left(el, position(',' in el)-1) 
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(abc) as el
);
```

Comment: благодарю, работает как надо ..